# Wrong values being updated in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update, row

$salt2I am working on a login system and am having a problem with updating my salt tables.  I am NOT an expert in sql BUT I know my way around.

My query to update is:

```
UPDATE hashTable SET `salt1` = 'salt1here' AND `salt2` = 'salt2here' WHERE `userID` = userID
```

`userID` is an integer value so I don't need to quote that.

When I update that table `salt1` is set to the value of `0`.  I am using php to create my sql query and that looks like:

```
UPDATE hashTable SET `salt1` = '$salt1' AND `$salt2` = 'salt2here' WHERE `userID` = $userID
```

> SIDE NOTE:  I know about sql injection and I do have protection
>   against that in my code.  In this case I do not need this because the
>   salt values are being generated by the script and user id is a value
>   returned by a function.  Any place where I do have user input I strip
>   slashes and have ways to prevent injection.

To me my sql query seems correct and I know that my values are correct because this is what a dynamically created query looks like:

```
UPDATE hashTable SET `salt1` = '9d6db1743e5e0cf1bb0e8cd799c0640231a10ec21e1612a6ed46e8ea16862835' AND `salt2` = '0824b2aac446ccfbd719645f84b13443cbcf59ee4e6dabace8c421ff6a8c6688' WHERE `userID` = 1374770432
```

I have even entered that in directly to phpMyAdmin and it says `0 rows affected`  but still changes my `salt1` row to `0`.

I am somewhat baffled because it seems like I'm doing everything correctly but obviously I am not.

Comment: Please, **do not** insert data using string interpolation without using [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: Please READ my post again.  I am ALREADY taking precautions that I DID NOT include in the code example.

Comment: If it's not blindingly obvious you're doing it, and by that I mean `mysql_real_escape_string` is right there in the middle of your query, then it's not safe to presume it's escaped. If you miss even *one* of these, your entire application can be destroyed. That's why using parameterized queries is highly recommended compared to this dangerous and error-prone way of composing with string concatenation. When you say you use "strip slashes" I am extremely worried because that does nothing for SQL injection protection.

Comment: It's not really necessary to show that I am I am using `mysql_real_escape_string` (which should be `mysqli_real_escape_string` by the way) in my example. Plus I have already explained that I am taking precautions and that I don't need to use the escape string function on these variables because they are private and inside private functions as well as the fact that they are not being populated by user input and no where close to being populated by the user. I only have a few functions that are handling use input and I can assure you that I am securing the input.

Comment: If you're using `mysqli` then what's your excuse for not using parameterized queries? It's not hard, and it makes it abundantly clear that everything is okay. This line of code would automatically fail any SQL injection audit.

Comment: Mostly cause I have no idea of what those are haha.

Comment: I guess that's as good an excuse as any, but it's easy to fix. What you need is to employ the [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method on your query. The examples there should give you an idea of how it works. It's literally just one more line and if you use this in a disciplined fashion, you'll have queries that are readable, auditable, and safe from injection bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL query is wrong;

```
UPDATE hashTable 
SET `salt1` = '$salt1' AND `$salt2` = 'salt2here' 
WHERE `userID` = $userID
```

...should be...

```
UPDATE hashTable 
SET `salt1` = '$salt1', `$salt2` = 'salt2here' 
WHERE `userID` = $userID
```

Currently, you're doing an `AND` operation between `$salt1` and `$salt2 = 'salt2here'` (which would seem to return 0 in this case) and store that in `salt1`.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I can't believe i didn't catch that!

Comment: @EvanStoddard Always easier to find errors looking over someone else's shoulder than being the one sitting there writing the code :)

Comment: Isnt it SET `salt1` = '$salt1' AND `salt2` = '$salt2here'

Comment: @Mihai It's `SET a=b, c=d, ...` and not with `AND`.

Comment: It appears to still be doing the same thing with this query as well.  I know that the `userID`'s match and it works when I only update one value but it doesn't like to do both.

Comment: I agree it is odd that it follows the pattern `s='$s1', \`$s2\`='s2'` where it's variable/string, string/variable.